# Disable webbrowser print popup dialog on IE

Tags: c#, .net, popup, browser

I have a simple Web Browser Control that displays a local webpage and that webpage has records and a print function , but whenever i click on the print button inside webpage i being redirected to IE and the print Dialog pops up , what i want is to disable being redirected to any other browser and display the print dialog from my web browser control.

I have searched a lot for a solution but the only thing that kind of logic accepted is :

```
    private void webBrowser1_NewWindow(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

But didn`t work.....

Here is the JavaSCript Function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printDiv(printDiv)
{

 //calledFromJSHandlerFunction(document.getElementById(printDiv).innerHTML);
    var w = window.open("about:blank");
    w.document.write(document.getElementById(printDiv).innerHTML);
    w.print();
    w.close();

}
```

Finally hope you guys help me.

Comment: the js code attached to the print button is...?

Comment: @Boo i edit my question and added the JS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugging your javascript into my JS-to-English translator...

> Open a new window 
>   Write the div you want printed to the new window
>   Print just that div 
>   close the new window

The Print command only works on window objects.  So if you do not want to print the entire page, and you do not want to create a new window... you will have to create a new CSS and reference it in your HTML.  This new CSS will have the `media="print"` attribute, and will define all elements as non-visible (eg `visibility: hidden;`) except for the div you want printed.

Alternately you might be able to acheive the same thing by using an `IFRAME`.